# Rotate and resize image with jquery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image *img.png* with dimensions: width=300px, height=200px.
This image is in a div container:

```
<div class='thumbnail'> <img id='imgX' src='img.png'> </div>
```

And the CSS are:

```
div.thumbnail {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

div.thumbnail > img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The image is displayed nicely. However, dynamically I can rotate the image with jquery using:

```
$("#imgX").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
```

With this the image is rotated but it's out of the div container. How can I keep it inside?

Comment: Pls show us the image you are using ?

Comment: probably its better to rotate the entire thumbnail container $(".thumbnail").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean, but what about

```
div.thumbnail {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Good idea! But I'd rather resize the image. But what's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: `var image = $("#imgX"); image.css("width",image.height());` because after rotating 90deg the vertical edge is called width. But still needs some improvement.